# What is the probability of randomly generating a tautology?

Tags: probability, logic, stochastic-processes, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

Suppose we randomly generate a [classical Hilbert propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms) formula $F$ with $n$ variables, using the following method:

$F = x_i$ for each of $i \leq n$ with probability $\frac{1}{n+2}$.

$F = \neg F_1$, where $F_1$ is generated independently using the same method.

$F = F_1 \to F_2$, where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are generated independently using the same method.

It follows from the [extinction criterion for the Galton-Watson branching processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process#Extinction_criterion_for_Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process), that the process of generation will terminate with probability $1$ and thus our random formula is well defined.

My question is:

> What is the probability that $F$ is a tautology?

It is clearly less, than $\frac{2}{n+2}$. However, it is clearly greater, than $\frac{n}{(n + 2)^3}$ which is the probability of generating a formula of the form $x_i \to x_i$.

Comment: FYI, [Marek Zaionc](https://marekzaionc.staff.tcs.uj.edu.pl/papers.html) (see [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Zaionc+logic+density)) has done a lot of work similar to this.

Answer (score 3):

Nice question! I doubt that you'll find a closed form for arbitrary $n$, but I'll solve it for $n=1$, and higher values of $n$ could be treated analogously with more effort.

Classify the formulas according to which valuations satisfy them. For $n=1$, that makes $2^{2^1}=4$ different types of formulas: Those that are equivalent to $x_1$, those that are equivalent to $\neg x_1$, the tautologies and the contradictions. Denote the probabilities of generating one of these by $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, respectively. Then the recursive generation process implies the following equations:

\begin{eqnarray*}
a&=&\frac13(1+b+ca+ba+bd)\;,\\
b&=&\frac13(0+a+cb+ab+ad)\;,\\
c&=&\frac13(0+d+aa+bb+cc+ac+bc+da+db+dc+dd)\;,\\
d&=&\frac13(0+c+cd)\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

[According to Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%7B%281%2Bb%2Bc*a%2Bb*a%2Bb*d%29%2F3%3Da%2C%28a%2Bc*b%2Ba*b%2Ba*d%29%2F3%3Db%2C%28d%2Ba*a%2Bb*b%2Bc*c%2Ba*c%2Bb*c%2Bd*d%2Bd*c%2Bd*a%2Bd*b%29%2F3%3Dc%2C%28c%2Bc*d%29%2F3%3Dd%7D&dataset=), this system of equations has a solution

$$
a\approx0.485694\;,\\
b\approx0.226917\;,\\
c\approx0.211531\;,\\
d\approx0.075859\;.
$$

Thus, for $n=1$, the probability of generating a tautology is approximately $0.211531$.

Obviously, this will get pretty complicated pretty quickly with increasing $n$, as there are $2^{2^n}$ different classes of formulas to consider. This can be slightly reduced by a factor of about $n!$ by taking into account the symmetry under permutation of the variables, but even just for $n=2$ that leaves $12$ variables.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that a formula generated that way  is a tautology is

$$\frac{1}{n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^3})$$

for large $n$.

To demonstrate this, let's call the probability that our formula is always true as $x$ and that our formula is always false as $y$.

Notice the following facts:

$x_i$ is sometimes true and sometimes false.

$\neg A$ is always true iff $A$ is always false.

$\neg A$ is always false iff $A$ is always true.

$x_i \to A$ is always true iff either $A = x_i$ or $A$ is always true.

$x_i \to A$ is true when $x_i$ is false (which sometimes happens)

$A \to x_i$ is always true iff either $A = x_i$ or $A$ is always false.

$A \to x_i$ is true when $x_i$ is true (which sometimes happens)

THe probability of generating any formula of type different from above mentioned ones is $O(\frac{1}{n^3})$

From this we can derive the following system of equations:

$$x = \frac{y}{n+2} + \frac{n}{n+2}(\frac{n}{(n+2)^2} + x + y) + O(\frac{1}{n^3})$$

$$y = \frac{x}{n+2} + O(\frac{1}{n^3})$$

When solving this system of equations we get $x = \frac{1}{n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^3})$, Q.E.D.

Comment: Why is the probability of a formula in some other form $O(n^{-3})$?

Comment: @MJD, because a formula of some other form should be of the form $A \to B$ where neither $A$ or $B$ is $x_i$. Probability of $A$ not being $x_i$ is $\frac{2}{n+2}$, for $B$ it is the same. And the probability to chose $\to$ first is $\frac{1}{n+2}$. And because everything is done independently, total probability is $\frac{4}{(n+2)^3}$.